# Qt Creator error - "Does not name a type"

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to Qt Creator and I'm trying to define a Database the takes a vector as its parameter. I already have the code for the Database and here is what I am doing to instantiate the object.

```
public:
    vector<CEmployee*> records;
    CDatabase all_emps(records);
```

I keep getting the error that "records is not a type" though and I don't quite understand why since I've define records as a vector right above it. I've tried changing records to simply vector but that creates other errors elsewhere in my code. If anyone could point me in a direction for how to fix this it would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using `using namespace std;`?  If you are [please stop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice).  If you are not then you forgot the `std::` in front of `vector`

Comment: Vector header included ? And use `std::vector`.

Comment: I've tried both of those options but continue to get the same error. The vector line is not where the error appears. It appears on the CDatabase all_emps(records) line

Comment: @lantakli What did you mean to do with `CDatabase all_emps(records);`?

Comment: I need to add a vector of employees into this database. Each time I click a button in my project another employee will be added to the vector and subsequently into the database.

Comment: You ask about the code, but you don't provide any. What's a `CEmployee`? What's a `CDatabase`? The declaration of `all_emps` doesn't make much sense: a function return all employees that takes records as an argument and returns a database? I think you have it wrong way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `records` is not a type, it's the name of a member variable. You probably meant this:

```
public:
  // member variable declaration
  std::vector<CEmployee*> records;
  // method declaration, taking a vector of CEmployee* as an argument
  CDatabase all_emps(std::vector<CEmployee*> records);
```

I have no idea, though, why `records` is a publicly visible member, as it seems to be an implementation detail, and why `all_emps` returns a `CDatabase`.

Maybe this would make more sense:

```
private:
  /// A database used to manage the data.
  CDatabase m_db;
public:
  /// Returns all employee records from the database.
  std::vector<CEmployee*> all_employees();
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have `#include <vector>` and `using std::vector` somewhere, or simply use `std::` prefix.
2. You cannot have the syntax `CDatabase all_emps(records);` in a class definition. It gets treated as a member function declaration, where you specify the parameter type as `records` (parameter name is not required, the return type is `CDatabase`). `records` is not a type.

You have two choices:

1. Use [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

   ```
   Database all_emps{records};
   ```
2. Use constructor and [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

   ```
   MyClass
   {
       vector<CEmployee*> records;
       CDatabase all_emps;

   public:
       MyClass(/* possibly vector<CEmployee*> const& records*/) :
       records(/* possibly records*/),
       all_emps(records)
       {
       }

       ...
   };
   ```

Comment: I don't think that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I need to create an instance on CDatabase (which is another .h file that I have already created). In the constructor in this .h file CDatabase takes in a vector<CEmployee*>. I'm not sure where member initializer lists would fit into this